# How to deploy a Visual Studio 2012 Windows Form application which uses Crystal Reports in another machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have created a **C# Windows Forms Application** in **Visual Studio 2012** (and **SQL Server 2012**) which some reports using **SAP Crystal Reports**. I have used '***CRforVS_13_0_12.exe***' (Crystal Reports Development for VS 2012) in my development computer (*Windows 8 | .NET 4.5 | 64-bit*). And it perfectly worked in the debugging mode.

Then I made a **setup.exe** of the software to deploy it in another computer (*Windows 7 | .NET 4.5.2 installed explicitly | 64-bit*). In that computer, I have installed the Crystal Reports Runtime '***CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12.msi***'.

When I install and run my application in the deployed computer, everything works fine including all CRUD operations for database, except the reports. When I try to view a report, It gives me the following exception:

[image: Exception Message when trying to view Reports]

Please help me to solve me this problem. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the actual crystal report file on the target machine